# What is the Windows Mobile Registry setting to turn off Predictive Text?

Tags: windows-mobile, registry, windows-mobile-6.5

I need to have my program not use (or allow to be used) predictive text.

I know how to turn it off manually ([this web page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/v6-5/Turn-predictive-text-touch.aspx) shows how).

But I need to do it programmatically.  The best way seems to be by a registry change.  Anyone happen to know what that registry setting is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure this is standardized.  For example, looking at the link you posted, my phone (and HTC HD2) doesn't have that exact set of options.  It looks like the SIP on my phone is made by Tegic.  To turn on word completion on this phone, I adjust the following registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Tegic\eT9]
"MultitapWordCompletion"=dword:00000001
```

This is also a good time to not just toss you a fish, but show you how to fish (i.e. how did I find this value?).

- Connect your device to your dev PC.
- Open Remote Registry Editor
- From the Registry menu, export the registry to a file.  I usually start with just the HKLM branch since that's where 90% of changes take place
- On the phone, change the setting you're interested in and make sure you click "Done" , "ok" or whatever to save the change.
- In Remote Registry Editor refresh the Registry list.
- Export the registry again.
- Use your favorite compare tool (I like Araxis Merge, but any diff tool will work) to compare the two files.

The key you're after will show up (assuming it's saved in the registry).

Comment: Good stuff!  Thanks for the idea on how to figure it out!  I am exporting now.

Comment: Turns out it is in `HKCU\ControlPanel\Sip\SuggWords` for my Symbol MC 75.  1=On and 0=Off